# How to read PLC (RFC1006) data with .NET

Tags: c#, plc

I'm looking for a good way of reading PLC-Data. I found this right here: https://github.com/killnine/s7netplus

Unfortunately this works for siemens plc only. I looked a while for another library, but could not find the right one. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance =)

Best regards,
Zuendi

Comment: What is interface (Ethernet, RS232, RS485, ...) and what is communication standard (Modbus, EtherCAT, ProfiNET,...)? What is your PLC?

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. I want to use Ethernet. The idea is to be able to read data out of multiple plc. This should not be limited to Siemens.

Comment: Often different manufacturers have their own communication methods. So it's not quite easy to create a program that reads from multiple sources without creating a separate communication for each. Perhaps you should list what manufacturers you need and find a c# library / create one of your own for each of them. Other solution would be to use a OPC server that collects data from all kind of devices and you could read it from there.

Comment: You cannot create universal application. There are communication protocols and there is no protocol that is supported by all PLCs. Especially Siemens. they have their own ProfiNET interface. If you make it for Siemens it will work only for Siemens or mostly for Siemens. I can only suggest to look into MQTT as a communication protocol, as it is Ethernet based and in the next 5 years will be supported by all major manufactures. Actually it is already have a huge support.

Comment: Ok you gave me allot to think about. Thank you. I guess I'll have to get some plcs for testing and start with this library. Mqtt is something I didn't think about for this issue. Maybe that helps too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AdvancedHMI which is a .NET solution. It has a range of communication drivers for various PLCs such as Allen Bradley, Beckhoff, Omron, Modbus, etc.

Comment: Oh cool thank you. That realy sounds like a thing to try out.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty vague as is, however the closest thing you’re going to get to a universal interface to all PLCs is probably OPC-UA.  Several major PLC vendors support this out of the box (Siemens S1500, Beckhoff TwinCAT, others) and many others supply server-side software that translates the PLC’s proprietary protocol into OPC-UA.

There is a fairly complete .net implementation of OPC-UA.

http://opcfoundation.github.io/UA-.NETStandard/

Comment: Thank you. Yes OPC-UA is something I already work with. But to be able to handle RFC1006 as well i thought maybe someone can help me with this. It's quite hard to find the needed information online. Also I don't know if RFC1006 is specifically for siemens plc. If so, then I don't have a problem at all.